# Adding two int16s to make a single standard int

Tags: arduino, int, atmega, 16-bit, mpu6050

At the beginning of my code I start nine variables:

```cpp
int16_t ax, ay, az;
int16_t gx, gy, gz;
int16_t xc, yc, zc;
```

Later on I collect the data from my gyro/accelerometer (the MPU6050):

```cpp
accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
accelgyro.getRotation(&gx, &gy, &gz);
```

Now I would like to set the value of `xc` to the sum of `ax` and `gx`.

Here is what I am currently using:

```cpp
&xc == &ax & &gx;
```

So far this has not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just xc = ax + gx;

== is for comparison.  It returns true if the two things on either side are equal and false if not.  = is for assigning a value to something.  The & symbol is to get the memory address of a variable.  If you're not trying to add the memory addresses then you don't want the &.  In those function calls the function is expecting a pointer apparently so that's why the & is there.  Enough can't be said for going through a quick basic C++ tutorial to pick stuff like this up.  This will be a very frustrating experience otherwise.

Comment: Can you take a look at my other question please?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382121/mpu6050-compounding-data-possibility